# Using filters in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My AngularJS app shows a list of dogs. The user can select some of those dogs using checkboxes, and then click a Delete button to delete the selected dogs. Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
    <td>{{dog.name}}</td>
    <td>{{dog.breed}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="dog.checked"></td>
</tr>

<button ng-click="deleteDogs(dogs)">Delete</button>
```

I'm trying to understand the best way to do this in Angular. At present, my `ng-click` simply invokes `deleteDogs(dogs)` and that controller method tests if each dog is checked before deleting it. It works, but I don't like it. In particular I don't like that I'm passing the entire list of dogs to `deleteDogs()`.

So, I wrote a custom `isChecked` filter to test if an object has `checked=true` in the hope of doing this:

```
<button ng-click="deleteDogs(dogs | filter:isChecked)">Delete</button>
```

or even this:

```
<button ng-click="deleteDogs(dogs | filter:{checked:true})">Delete</button>
```

but both cause Angular parse errors. Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filter in the click handler. Pass in `$filter` to your controller, then:

```
$filter("filterNameHere")(input, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

You could also bind your filter to the scope, if you were dead-set on doing this in your template:

```
$scope.myFilter = $filter("filterNameHere");
```

Then:

```
<thing ng-click="doSomething(myFilter(someValue, someArg))"></thing>
```

Comment: Very helpful answers from Darryl and FlorianTopf below but I'm accepting this answer because it shows a general solution for using filters in ng-click, even though I may end up implementing this differently. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try adding an ng-click to your checkbox that adds that dog to an array of dogs to delete with the index from the original dogs array.  That solves your problem of dealing with the entire dogs array and makes your function very fast because you can then simply splice out the unwanted entries.

another approach would be instead of the checkbox to put a delete icon and when clicked you could simply run a method attached to each dog object to remove itself from the array (and make your API call if that applies).

Comment: This is even smarter as my proposed solution, though it might be that the button needs to be outside of ng-repeat.

Comment: Angular is so much easier once you start attaching methods to your objects. I left off that I also tend to create list objects with methods.  I find that very useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't use filters that way afaik.

I expect you are calling the `deleteDogs()` function from the same scope as `dogs`. So why passing the dogs list at all?

I'd suggest that you simply write a `deteleDogs()` function without any argument, which does the following:

`dogs = dogs.filter(function (dog) { return !dog.checked; });`

This will filter the dogs array appropriately and keep only those which are not checked.